# String Length Limitation with UIAlertViews in IOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uialertview

I'm working in a new iOS app and I noticed the following issue installing the app in iOS7 environment.

After opening the app by first time, our app displays a popup with the AGB's that needs to be accepted in order to start using it.
We used a `UIAlertView` and it worked fine until we tested with iOS7. Actually the alert pops up and seems to have content since I can see a huge scrollbar! But the strange thing is that the text is not shown at all.... After playing a bit with the text I noticed that the new `UIAlertView` of iOS7 has some kind of string length limit...

Has anybody else noticed that? Is this normal, or an iOS 7 bug?

I found that [custom](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) `UIAlertView` works, but I would rather use a native API if possible.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: It looks something like that! just replace the longTextVar with a really huge text. UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"agb"  message: longTextVar delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

Comment: Happens when the text has more than 15087 chars and I don't know the reason.

Comment: I think you should present a custom modal view with a `UITextView` inside. Per Apple's documentation: "Alert views display a concise and informative alert message to the user." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView

Comment: Maybe you are right but seems strange to me that the documentation tell nothing about length limitations. Maybe it's just a bug. To solve the problem finally I decided to use the custom UIAlertView for iOS7... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Length limitation are rarely documented because they are difficult to find. 15k letters in an alert are something you shouldn't do because alerts shouldn't be used for long texts.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what you say. post a radar maybe -- there is no reason for this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    longTextVar = [longTextVar stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", i];
}
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"agb" message: longTextVar delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

breaks it, while 1000 appends work

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same UIAlertView problem, where in the simulator the scrollview was big enough to hold the long text but text was not there. After I tried the show same lenght message on iphone alertview did show the message.

Therefore, I think this is a simulator issue, not really a limitation, and that is why it is not documented.