# Parsing content from HTML (stringWithContentsOfFile) displaying empty on alert view in iOS 7+ versions

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, ios7, html-parsing

I am Parsing content from HTML file (stringWithContentsOfFile) which is displaying empty on alert view in iOS 7+ versions but working fine in lower versions.
[Screenshot of empty alert in iOS7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0GPf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than contents of File why not fire the url

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:<#(NSURL *)#> options:<#(NSDataReadingOptions)#> error:<#(NSError *__autoreleasing *)#>]
```

Is your NSData empty? Check if the url firing results in error or produces something as NSData.

Better convert NSData to NSString like:

```
 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8encoding];
```

Comment: how to set this str value in ios7 alert view.

Comment: Set the string as the message of UIAlertView

Comment: yes,it is the message but i am having this str contains of 400 lines.

Comment: Check this link then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520260/string-length-limitation-with-uialertviews-in-ios7

Comment: Per Apple's documentation: "Alert views display a concise and informative alert message to the user." It supposedly happens when the text has more than 15087 chars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55315/discussion-between-user3687118-and-aravintha-bashyam-c).